# jquery nice number spinner how to let work step number js only for certain class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, numbers

I have this nice number spinner from https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Number-Input-Spinner-jQuery-Nice-Number.html. and I have this script to let the input step 0.1 digit at a time but I want to let it work only for a certain class.
how can I do?
code:
query in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.nice-number.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="js/jquery.nice-number.js"></script>
```

body:

```
<input type="number" value="1.0" name="qty" step="0.1" max="99999" min="0.1" class="ist">
    <input type="number" step="1">
    <script>


        $(function () {

            $('input[type="number"]').niceNumber({
                if($('.ist')) {
                onDecrement: ($el, newValue, settings) => {
                    $el.val(Math.round((newValue + 0.9) * 100) / 100);
                    console.log($el.val())
                },
                    onIncrement: ($el, newValue, settings) => {
                        //console.log($el.val())
                        $el.val(Math.round((newValue - 0.9) * 100) / 100);
                        console.log($el.val())
                    }
            }
        });

        });


    </script>
```

Comment: `$('input[type="number"].class')` Did you try that?

Comment: it's working thank u very much